# Html5 App vs Android or iphone app speed comparision

Tags: android, iphone, html

I want to compare the speed of my html5 based app with the same app built using native tools on android or iphone using java or objective-C? Typically i want to compare the loading time,response time, speed in case of canvas animation etc. Can anyone tell me is there any tool available or is there any other way i could test the speed of both apps?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much animation there is, it will run extremely poor on android.  On iOS 5 with the new iPhone 4s, it will be pretty good.

Natively will blow them both away though and there really won't be any comparison.  With Android, there are too many phone's out there that are still on 2.1 and have sub-par hardware.  Native is the only way to go to target them with animations.

Comment: Actually i want to compare the speed for other simple apps as well like load time and response time do u know any tool for that?

Comment: Not off the bat.  Are you looking at the html5 app being in a webview (native) or just downloaded and saved with the cache manifest?  The startup time on the app depends on code/libraries you are loading.  You'd really have to do the profiling yourself unfortunately.  Depending on the complexity, you could see a big difference with the webview being slower.

Comment: actually i would be comparing the speed's of (loadtime- response time) of my html5 phonegap app with native apps using java or objective c. i want to know how can i compare the load time and repsonse time of both the apps?